# Why isn't my keyboard disappearing when I press the RETURN key?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, keyboard

This is my SecondViewController Class :

```
class SecondViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var txtNewItem: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var lblResult: UILabel!
@IBAction func btnAddNewItem(_ sender: Any) {
    let itemsObject = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "items")
    var items:[String]

    if let tmpItem = itemsObject as? [String] {
        if txtNewItem.text == "" {
            //Alert message if empty txtNewItem is ""            
        } else {
            items = tmpItem
            items.append(txtNewItem.text!)
            UserDefaults.standard.set(items, forKey: "items")
        }
    } else {
        items = [txtNewItem.text!]
        UserDefaults.standard.set(items, forKey: "items")
    }
    txtNewItem.text = ""
}

override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
    self.view.endEditing(true)
}

func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    textField.resignFirstResponder()
    return true
    }
}
```

The 2 functions (touchesBegan and textFieldShouldReturn) working perfectly into my FisrtViewController and many others apps.

I don't know why in this case, if I click everywhere the keyboard disappears and is working fine but, when I press the return key, the keyboard does NOT disappear.

I tested it on XCode simulator and on my iPhone 7 and iPad Air 2 the problem continue on this 3 iDevices.

N.B: I voluntary deleted the viewDidLoad and didReceiveMemoryWarning because I don't have code into these functions.

Comment: Use `self.view.endEditing(true)` in `textFieldShouldReturn` as well.

Comment: Sorry, I try with this line of code and isn't working...

Comment: Have you initialised the textfield's delegate to self?? I don't see that in your code

Comment: `override func viewDidLoad(){ super.viewDidLoad(); textField.delegate = self; }`

Comment: Thank you Xcoder123

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must add these lines of code:

```
override func viewDidLoad(){
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.txtNewItem.delegate = self
}
```

Into `viewDidLoad()` in order for this to work! Now it assigns your class to the textField's delegate. Glad it helped!

Comment: Better yet, since the OP is using outlets, set the text field's delegate in Interface Builder. No code required.

Comment: It dependes on the type of dev you are. Some, like me, like having both the delegates and the methods of that delegate in code, while others may like the drag and drop style more. Code has the advantage of working with textfields created both programmatically and through code, that's why I've chosen that.

Comment: I do everything in code so I get what you are saying. But if a newer developer is using storyboards and outlets, etc., it seems they may as well also connect the delegate in the storyboard/xib. But I agree that ultimately it is up to the developer to choose what works for them. I really just wanted to point out this option to the OP so they don't think the only option is to set the delegate via code.